# How to get item when selected listview on xamarin android?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, selecteditem

```
string[] items = new string[] { "Alternative Rock","Classical"}

lst.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {    
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTx=this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    TracksByGenres fragTrack=new TracksByGenres();
    //get our item from listview

    fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer,fragTrack,.....);  
    fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTx.Commit();
};
```

**TracksByGenres.cs**

```
public async override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
    base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstancesState);
    // what do I write?
}
```

How can I get the selected item form the `ListView` on Xamarin.Android and create a back button that will return old fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ListFragment` subclass override the `OnListItemClick` to receive the item that the clicked on

```
public class myListFragment : ListFragment
{
    string[] data =  { "Alternative Rock","Classical" } ;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
       base.OnCreate (bundle);
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this,
       Resource.Layout.TextViewItem, data);
       ListAdapter = adapter;
    }

    protected override void OnListItemClick (ListView l, View v,
    int position, long id)
    {
       base.OnListItemClick (l, v, position, id);
       Toast.MakeText (this, data [position],
       ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }        
}
```

> Android.App.ListFragment.OnListItemClick Method
>
> This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.ListFragment.OnListItemClick/p/Android.Widget.ListView/Android.Views.View/System.Int32/System.Int64/

Comment: I use fragment. That not Activity

Comment: I updated the answer, override the `OnListItemClick`  in your `ListFragment` subclass

Answer (score 1):

`ItemClickEventArgs` `Position` will tell you the index of the selected item

```
lst.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {

  var selected = items[e.Position];
}
```

Comment: How to get items[e.Position] from different fragment.ragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer,fragTrack,items[e.Position]);

Answer (score 0):

simply create a method for ListView.ItemClick

```
mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
```

from within the method you can retrieve the index of clicked item

```
void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, e.Position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```